# How to sum all the arrays inside a list of arrays?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array, confusion-matrix

I am working with the confusion matrix. So for each loop I have an array (confusion matrix). As I am doing 10 loops, I end up with 10 arrays. I want to sum all of them. 
So I decided that for each loop I am going to store the arrays inside a list --I do not know whether it is better to store them inside an array.

And now I want to add each array which is inside the list.

So If I have:

```
    5 0 0       1 1 0
    0 5 0       2 4 0
    0 0 5       2 0 5
```

The sum will be:

```
    6 1 0
    2 9 0 
    2 0 10
```

This is a picture of my confusion matrices and my list of arrays:
[image]

This is my code:

```
   list_cm.sum(axis=0)
```

Comment: Is there a question? Have you tried `sum(list_cm)`?

Comment: How do I sum all the arrays which are inside the list?

Comment: `np.sum(list_arrays,axis=0)`?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Just `sum` the list:

```
>>> sum([np.array([[5,0,0],[0,5,0],[0,0,5]]), np.array([[1,1,0],[2,4,0],[2,0,5]])])
array([[ 6,  1,  0],
       [ 2,  9,  0],
       [ 2,  0, 10]])
```

Comment: To clarify, this is Python's built-in `sum()` function, not `np.sum()`.